# assign() and '%>%' dplyr operator

Tags: r, dplyr, assign

At the end of calculation, I would like to assign result to variable, I tried `assign()` and `x = (.)`, `x <- (.)`

`(4+5) %>% assign("x", .)`
`> Error: object 'x' not found`

how to interpret `dplyr's` `'.'` notation sign ?

Comment: add `envir = .GlobalEnv` as an argument to `assign`. Or just use `->`. I think it's awful, but some people like things like `1:5 %>% mean -> x`.

Comment: I like `->` why you don't ? what is better ?

Comment: I just find it difficult to read. I understand the "pipe forward" point of view, but  if I'm going to assign a pipe result I still like to have the assignment first, `x <- ...`.

Answer (score 1):

`(4+5) %>% assign("x", ., inherits = TRUE)`